# Weird image movement in header on click of another link (appears in IE only)

Tags: html, css

I have an odd problem with an image in my [site](http://bensouthgate.com) header. In the code below, the image in the RSS feed link jumps to the place of the projects link when the projects link is clicked. AFAIK, this only occurs in IE (I'm currently using v10.0)

```
<header id="primary">
   <a href="http://bensouthgate.com"> ben's stuff </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <a href="../posts.php"> posts </a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <a href="../projects.php"> projects </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <a href= "../about.php" > about </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <a href="../feed.xml"> <img src="../i/RSS-icon.gif" height="30px" width="30px" style="border:none;"> </a>
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://bensouthgate.com/favicon.ico" />
</header>
```

I'm new to CSS and HTML, so I'm sure this is a simple issue - but I don't know where to start looking.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Here is my stylesheet (in all of its beautiful ignorance):

```
/* 
Stylesheet for bensouthgate.com
Written 07/21/13
*/

/*************************
  Fonts
*************************/

/* Element Selectors */
html, body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    color:#5e5f5c;
}

body
{
    background: #fff;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
    font-weight: 300;

}



header#primary
{
    float:left;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-indent:15%;
    top:0;
    line-height:2;
    font-size:30;
    background-color: #33798d;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    z-index:10;
}


/* ID Selectors */
header#primary a {
  color:white;
  display:inline-block; 
  float:left; 
  padding-right:5px

}

header#primary a:hover a:visited {
  color:#92948e;
}


h3 {
  margin-top:50px;
}

h4 {
  text-align: center;
}

code {
  font-size:16;
}

pre code {
  margin-top:-10px;
  font-size:14;
}



a {color:#33798d;}
a:link {text-decoration:none;}
a:visited {text-decoration:none;}
a:active{text-decoration:none;}
a:hover { 
  color:#439eb8;
}

sup { 
  vertical-align: top; 
  font-size: 0.6em; 
}

svg { 
  margin-left:auto; 
  margin-right:auto; 
  display:block;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: square;
}


#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}


#logo
{
  color:white;
  background-color:#92948e;
  width:100%;
  padding-top:60px;
  text-indent:18%;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 1.7;
  font-size: 20;
  display:block;
}

/* Post Content Formatting */
#main
{
    float: left;
    padding-left: 15%;
    padding-right:15%;
    padding-bottom:80px;
}



/* Class Selectors */
.footer
{
    font-size: 12;
    padding-top:5px;
}

.bottom-space {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

/* Float Clearing Group Classes */
.group:before,
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.group:after {
  clear: both;
}
.group {
  zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: To be clear: This happens no matter what link you click in your `#primary`. Please provide your relevant CSS code which handles the links. Also rebuilding your problem in a jsfiddle.net will help as well (If you fix the issue, other users won't be able to see it in the link you provided)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have some mistakes in your code. Here are some small tips:

1. `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://bensouthgate.com/favicon.ico" />` belongs to the `<head>` area of your html document.
2. Don't use `&nbsp;` to create space between elements. Use margin instead.
3. To create a navigation like yours, we fancy CSS people *usually* use an unordered list (`ul`). I show you an example with your data:

*Note, that I have removed your `float: left;` to get this to work.*

**HTML:**

```
<head>
    <!-- what else you've got in your head-area -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://bensouthgate.com/favicon.ico" />
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="navigation">
        <li><a href="#">ben's stuff</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">posts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="RSS-icon.gif" alt="RSS" /></a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- the rest of your code -->
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.navigation {
    list-style: none; /* removes the list bullets from ul */
    padding: 0; /* removes standard padding from ul */
}

.navigation li {
    display: inline-block; /* makes your menu items display horizontally */
    margin-right: 30px; /* creates space between your menu items */
}
```

You need to replace the `#` with your paths again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! This removed the movement. I would upvote, but I don't have enough reputation haha. It looks like it might have created another issue though - probably due to my spaghetti css. There is now a great gap between the top <ul> and the first header on my index page -> any idea as to why. Thanks again!

Comment: This is due to the standard margin of the `<ul>`. Set `margin: 0;` on `.navigation`. But please note: You should ask a new question for each issue you have. I only answered, because it was a fairly small one.

Comment: Thanks, I'll make a separate post next time.

Answer (score 0):

Removing float:left from header#primary and padding-top from #logo eliminates the image movement in IE10 and renders logo correctly. It seems there is no diference with page before clicking in header.